# Skype on gnome logout with webcam and screen sharing

Tags: 12.04, skype

Syslog: [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qXJFKZLQ)

Every time I turn on my webcam and start the screen sharing my Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity 3D) logs out and show me the login screen.
The syslog above shows the relevant lines. Does someone know any solution?

Btw: My skype version: Skype 4.0.0.8

Comment: Does it also happen if you stop webcam before starting screen share?

Comment: By the way, does screen share works if you don't start webcam at all?

Comment: I see that it works here on my new notebook. Sorry. I think its because of the update. I will check it at my home computer if the problem still appears.

Answer (score 2):

Approaches I suggest you to try in your home computer:

Before starting skype:

- Create another user in your computer, for test purposes. It will have a clean environment perfect for testing. This will rule out any broken settings in your account. Log in as this user, start skype, and see if it works.
- Make sure your webcam is working fine, using annother application. I suggest `cheese`.. That will rule out any hardware issues. Also test the webcam using the `test` user you created.
- Delete the ~/.Skype hidden folder in your user's home folder. It will reset your preferences, but it may also fix the bug.

Now start skype. It should probably work.

If not, please post any relevant logs and/or messages and I'll help you out.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove skype: `sudo apt-get remove skype` and remove user configuration files `sudo rm /home/USERNAME/.Skype/` then reinstall skype `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: Could not reproduce the error again. Sorry. Now it seems to freeze Unity randomly when having webcam or screen sharing active.

Comment: 1. have you removed skype?  2. have you removed configuration files and changed the USERNAME into your actual username 3. have you reinstalled skype and reboot your ubuntu ?

Comment: try to get this software https://github.com/kapliars/doctor-skype